# Oddity in how Python3 handles lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

This:

```
import sys, re

# List of file names to exclude from analysis
excludes = map(re.compile, [
    '/\.svn/',
    '/\.hg/', ])


def regmatch(pathName):
    # Print the argument then any regular expressions that match it
    sys.stdout.write("::" + pathName + "\n")
    for pattern in excludes:
        sys.stdout.write("\t" + str(re.search(pattern, pathName)) + "\n")

regmatch("one/.hg/one")
regmatch("two/.hg/two")
regmatch("thr/.hg/thr")
```

in Python2.7 produces the expected result, i.e., for each call it prints the argument, followed by the list of results of matching against each re.  However, in Python3 the output is:

```
::one/.hg/one
        None
        <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb74bb870>
::two/.hg/two
::thr/.hg/thr
```

i.e., it seems to forget the contents of `excludes` after the first call.  What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, in Python 3.x, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) *doesn't return a list, but an iterator*.

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

So, once the iterator is exhausted, it cannot be used again. In your first call to `regmatch`, the `excludes` iterator is exhausted. So, further iteration with `for` loop, in the subsequent `regmatch` calls, will exit immediately.

To fix this, you can explicitly create a list, like this

```
excludes = list(map(re.compile, ['/\.svn/', '/\.hg/']))
```

Or you can use list comprehension, like this

```
excludes = [re.compile(item) for item in ('/\.svn/', '/\.hg/')]
```